# Точка входа не найдена - Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

При установке visual community уже в который раз выбивает ошибку

> Точка входа в процедуру nextafterf не найдена в библиотеке DLL
>   MSVCR120_CL0400.dll

Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с подобным. Что делать с этим?

Comment: Ошибка именно при установке студии? Какую версию и на какую венду ставите?

Comment: Да, при установке. Сразу после этого закрывается bootstrap с иконкой visual. 2017, windows 7.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что 2017-я студия для 7-й венды слишком нова. Попробуйте 2013. У меня старше ее на 7-ку не ставилось :-(

Comment: У меня на 7 2017 идет